# 301 redirect ssl in htaccess for codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, ssl, redirect

This is my htaccess for codiegniter base website.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /index\.php(/[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*))?$ example.com/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
Redirect 301 /blog/detail/4 https://example.com/blog/detail/4/blog-title
```

This is redirected url after use 301 :

```
https://example.com/blog/detail/4/blog-title/blog-title/blog-title/5/blog-title/blog-title/blog-title/blog-title/blog-title/blog-title/blog-title/blog-title/blog-title/blog-title/blog-title/blog-title/blog-title/blog-title/blog-title/blog-title/blog-title
```

I want this url:

```
https://example.com/blog/detail/4/blog-title
```